# Streaming video using stream of images

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a stream of images to make a .flv video. I can make video using those streams using ffmpeg but video is to be streamed live simultaneously.

I have already installed red5 for streaming.

Comment: Hi nicky, did you got any way to do what you needed?
I need similar thing (streaming mpeg4 base on a group of pictures that are refreshed time to time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this thread may be of help
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=665607

It explains how to use `ffmpeg` and `ffserver` for live streaming *while the converted video is generated*.  This works even for infinite streams.

when you stream your video using `ffserver`, you may want to set a reverse-proxy on your main webserver so that your users do not need to type a port number for the video.

`ffmpeg` can read from image sequences, use `%d` to represent the incrementing number.  Just use the sequence as your input and  the `ffserver` stream as your output

Comment: i have installed red5.. i dont have video i have series of images which keeps on increasing

Comment: @nicky: `ffmpeg` can use a jpeg sequence as input.  I have added that to my answer.

Comment: but whenever i call this using %d to make video. images which is uploaede later are not included in that video and i cant append video in that video which is already playing..

Comment: If your image source supports it, you can have it frame the images in a MIME multipart stream and pass that to ffmpeg using a FIFO buffer (use `mkfifo`)  That will stream continuously.

Comment: @George Steel  mkfifo is not working is there any alternative

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing exactly this using this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -vcodec bmp -framerate 1 -i \\.\pipe\input_pipe -r 25 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rtsp rtsp://wowza.server.com:1935/app/stream
```

I'm generating the images in a c# app and writting as bmp to input_pipe, where ffmpeg will read them. My images get generated each second, so note the -framerate 1 in the input, and -r 25 in the output to generate a video at 25fps.

It is working almost perfect but I'm having an issue where the video takes about 20 seconds to be accessible from the wowza server.

Comment: isn't "-vcodec bmp" the same as "-c:v" ? So, why are you specifying it twice ?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to stream video, images will be too heavy.
Just create an .asx file with notepad that contains your video URL.
It's easy and it can be played with many players, even with Windows Media Player.
Here is simple ASX example:

```
<ASX>
<Entry>
<ref HREF="YourFilePath.mp4"/>
</Entry>
</ASX>
```

Good luck.